# Update a label from a task

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task

I'm trying to implement tasks in my program. I launch a task that will produce a log file, and after, I want to update the label to say "Log sucessfully saved".

Here is my code

```
Private Function Createlog(ByVal mylist As List(Of classTest))
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter("log_list.log")
        For index = 1 To mylist.Count - 1
            sw.WriteLine(mylist(index).comments)
        Next
        sw.Close()
        Try
            Me.Invoke(UpdateLabel("Log sucessfully saved"))
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return 1
    End Function

    Private Function UpdateLabel(ByVal text As String)
        Label1.Text = text
        Return 1
    End Function
```

I launch the task from the Main form in the Load() :

```
 Dim tasktest = Task(Of Integer).Factory.StartNew(Function() Createlog(theList))
```

(I don't know if it is better to use the factory or declare as a task and then task.Start())

I have the error on the label update :

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Label1' accessed from a thread
>   other than the thread it was created on.

Could you please explain why it doesn't work with the invoke method ? And do you have an alternative solution ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: In your UpdateLabel method, try refreshing your Label1 after setting it's text. This will force the label to repaint itself.  Example, label1.Refresh()

Comment: I cannot because the error is handled when I change the label1.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `UpdateLabel` should be a `Sub`, not a `Function`. Second, this line is wrong:

```
Me.Invoke(UpdateLabel("Log sucessfully saved"))
```

Read it again. You are, in order, executing the `UpdateLabel` function, then passing the result of that function to `Me.Invoke` (if you used `Sub` instead of `Function`, the compiler should have warned you about the error).

This doesn't raise any compiler errors because a `Function` declared without `As [Type]` is defaulted to `As Object`, that can be cast to anything. It should be:

```
Me.Invoke(Sub()
              UpdateLabel("Log sucessfully saved")
          End Sub)
```

To simplify, your code can be rewritten like this:

```
Private Sub Createlog(ByVal mylist As List(Of classTest))
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter("log_list.log")
    For index = 1 To mylist.Count - 1
        sw.WriteLine(mylist(index).comments)
    Next
    sw.Close()
    Me.Invoke(Sub()
                  Label1.Text = "Log sucessfully saved"
              End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful explaination and for the solution.